# Is it true that a continuous function with compact support is uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, uniform-continuity

I've been trying to prove the given $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb C$ continuous with compact support, $f$ is uniformly continuous.
I don't know if it's true or not, but it is highly plausible and it's interesting.

It's obvious that it's uniformly continuous on the support (because it is continuous on compact set), and outside the support (cause it's constant), separately. Could I use the continuity to show that it's uniformly continuous over all of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @DanielFischer: I did try to go that way, but as far as I can see for any $x\in \partial supp(f)$ there is a $\delta>0$ that would be good. but it is possible that $\aleph_0\leq|supp(f)|$ and therefore the bound could be not uniform.

Comment: You could also use a larger compact set, if $\operatorname{supp} f \subset [A,B]$, consider the restriction of $f$ to $[A-1,B+1]$, and patch together with $(-\infty,A-1/2]$ and $[B+1/2,+\infty)$. But, without that, if $\lvert x-y\rvert < \delta$, and $x\in\operatorname{supp} f$, $y\notin \operatorname{supp} f$, then there is a $z\in\partial \operatorname{supp} f$ between $x$ and $y$, and $\lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert = \lvert f(x) - f(z)\rvert$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compactly supported continuous function is uniformly continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445735/compactly-supported-continuous-function-is-uniformly-continuous)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The support is contained in a interval of the form $[-m,m]$ for $m$ large enough.

The function is uniformly continuous on $A=[-m-1,m+1]$ since $A$ is compact. Take $\epsilon >0$. From uniform continuity on $A$ for there exists $\delta>0$ such that 
for $|x-y|< \delta$ it implies that $ |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

We prove continuity on $\mathbb{R}$. For the previous $\epsilon$, the $\delta $ that does the work is 
$ \tilde{\delta}= \min (  1 , \delta  )$. Indeed for $|x-y| < \tilde {\delta}$ if $x,y \in A$ we have $|f(x)- f(y)|< \epsilon$, otherwise $x\in A^{c}$ the complement of $A$, but since $|x-y|<1$ it implies that $y\in \mathbb{R}/[-m,m]$ therefore $f(x)=f(y)=0$. So for all $|x-y|<\tilde{\delta}$ we get $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Similar idea can be executed on any metric space.

Answer (score 0):

Use the $\varepsilon$/$\delta$-definitions of continuity and uniform continuity.

(The $\delta$ that works in the support works outside as well.)

Comment: The definition of contiuity is local, the definition of uniform continuity isn't.